# Align grid items to the corners of the container

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to use [CSS Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) to align the items to stick to all 4 corners of the container box.

How would I do this? Does it make sense to use CSS grid or is it better to use flex box?

I have the following HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="box1">Box1</div>
    <div class="box2">Box2</div>
    <div class="box3">Box3</div>
    <div class="box4">Box4</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;  /* grid has two columns; content defines width */
  justify-content: space-between;    /* horizontal alignment of grid tracks */
  align-content: space-between;      /* vertical alignment of grid tracks */
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container > div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box2">Box2</div>
  <div class="box3">Box3</div>
  <div class="box4">Box4</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7jnr4yfx/)

Comment: +1...and FYI, I don't know if you thought about this before, though I just realized one can do interesting stuff with Flexbox and a pseudo, i.e. to force a line break and be able to corner these items (posted a solution).

Answer (score 5):

#### Two solutios:

### (1) use `position: absolute;`

- set your parent container to `position: relative;`
- using `position: absolute;` to those 4 div boxes then control the position with left, top, right, bottom

example below:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
}

.container div {
  background: aqua;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
}

.box1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box2 {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.box3 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box4 {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box2">Box2</div>
  <div class="box3">Box3</div>
  <div class="box4">Box4</div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
  galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
  containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

### (2) use CSS grid

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px auto 40px;
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
  padding: 0;
}

.container div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.box3 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 3;
}

.box4 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box2">Box2</div>
  <div class="box3">Box3</div>
  <div class="box4">Box4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to use CSS grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ to not break the document flow with position: absolute.

Comment: @Benedikt ok check the updated, add a padding on the container?

Comment: I know position absolute works but my interest is if this is possible with CSS Grid. See the link above.

Comment: @Benedikt 2nd solution using grid, refresh your page

Answer (score 3):

One can also do this using Flexbox, using a pseudo to push the 3rd and 4th item to a new line.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container > div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container > div:nth-child(n+3) {
  order: 2;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  order: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box2">Box2</div>
  <div class="box3">Box3</div>
  <div class="box4">Box4</div>
</div>
```

---

Update based on a comment.

For IE11 on Windows 7, it appears it has issues with the pseudo as a flex item, so the fix for that will be a `spacer` element.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container > div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container > div:nth-child(n+3) {
  order: 2;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.container .spacer {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box2">Box2</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="box3">Box3</div>
  <div class="box4">Box4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Benedikt Of course it does. How does it not work for you?, because in my IE11 it works perfect

Comment: Hm I'm using IE 11 on Windows 7. This is not Edge correct?

Comment: @Benedikt IE11, not Edge

Comment: @Benedikt Does this fiddle work for you? ... https://jsfiddle.net/adzst75c/

Comment: @Benedikt And this? ... https://jsfiddle.net/adzst75c/1/ ... show me screen shoot please, as I added a test text and wan't to see where it renders

Comment: @Benedikt This ... https://jsfiddle.net/adzst75c/2/ ... and this ... https://jsfiddle.net/adzst75c/3/

Comment: This works: .container .spacer {
  width: 100%;
}
Thanks a lot!