# two divs, one next to each other, in the same corner

Tags: html

How do I place two divs side by side in the same corner please? For example this is what I have so far (see snippet). I would like to have another div, lets say of blue color at the top left next to the existing red one. Is it also possible to place it below the red?

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>

<style>
    .box {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: red;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .box.top {
        top: 0;
    }

    .box.right {
        right: 0;
    }

    .box.left {
        left: 0;
    }

    .box.bottom {
        bottom: 0
    }
</style>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="main" style="background-color: pink; height: 100vh; width: 100%; position: relative;"></div>
    <div class="box top left"></div>
    <div class="box top right"></div>
    <div class="box bottom left"></div>
    <div class="box bottom right"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just use `left: 100px` if you want it after the red box in the top left or `top:100px` if you want it below (although your screen will have to be at least 300px tall) - please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Yes, fair enough, but can this be done without hard setting it please?

Comment: not with absolute positioning

Comment: if they need to have absolute positioning, you can use javascript to detect the position of one box and place the other next to it

Comment: You may want to have a look at a flex or grid approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925949/align-grid-items-to-the-corners-of-the-container

Comment: If it can be done without absolute positioning, then that should be ok too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of positioning the boxes themselves, consider create wrapper divs for all of your four corner elements. So, instead of having your four box divs, you would have this:

```
<div class="box-wrapper top left">
  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box blue"></div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper top right">
  <div class="box red"></div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper bottom left">
  <div class="box red"></div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper bottom right">
  <div class="box red"></div>
</div>
```

Now, use `display: flex` for the `box-wrapper` class and `flex-direction: row` so the elements get aligned horizontally. (You can assign different classes and configure the direction "per corner" if you like).

Here is a working example showing the case you mentioned (having a blue box right next to the red box in the top left corner): https://jsfiddle.net/uejw2yr3/ (If you want to have the box below, replace `flex-direction: row` with `flex-direction: column`)

If you like to know more on flexbox (try it, it's awesome) check this out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/